# How to include special characters when selecting text in the Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, text-editor

I've recently started following the recommendation to use $ as the first character in the name of all jQuery variables, so it's easy to differentiate them from normal JavaScript variables.

Unfortunately the JS editor in Visual Studio 2010 doesn't pick up the $ when I double-click to select a word, or when searching for "whole word".

I know some text editors (Textpad, for example) allow you to tweak which characters are included in words. Is there any way to control this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question, but the problem has gone away as the $ symbol is included automatically in VS 2012 and beyond.